# Understanding a conclusion through "elementary considerations about bilinear forms"

Tags: proof-explanation, bilinear-form, manifolds-with-boundary

I am having a hard time to understand how "elementary considerations about bilinear forms" can imply the following result:

> Let $E$ be a function space, 1 the constant function $x\mapsto 1$ and let $Q:E\times E\to\Bbb R$ be a bilinear form such that $Q(1,1)=0$ and $Q(\phi,\phi)\geq0$ for all $\phi\in E$. Then $Q(1,\phi)=0$ for all $\phi\in E$.

The reference is the paper [**Rigidity of Area-Minimizing Free Boundary Surfaces in Mean Convex Three-Manifolds** by *Lucas C. Ambrozio*](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1301.6257v2.pdf), page 6:

[image]

Comment: Is $Q$ supposed symmetrical ?

Comment: A quick guess is that if $Q$ is supposed symmetrical then by CS $|Q(1,\phi)|^2 \leq Q(1,1)Q(\phi,\phi) = 0$ which implies $Q(1,\phi)=0$.

Comment: @NAC I am not sure but I will verify. If this is the case I will let you know, so your comment can turn into a short answer. :-)

Comment: @NAC Yeap, the Second Variation of Area is symmetric. So in fact it follows from CS. I would accept it as an answer if you post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $Q$ seems symmetrical, from CS we have :
$$
|Q(1,\phi)|^2 \leq Q(1,1)Q(\phi,\phi) = 0
$$
which implies $Q(1,\phi)=0$.